# How do I close a stream when my Get Controller is deleted from memory?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the following package https://pub.dev/packages/get .

I have the following controller

```
class GroupController extends GetController{
  StreamController<GroupModel> _streamController = BehaviorSubject();
  Stream<GroupModel> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  GroupController(DatabaseService database, GroupModel group)
  {
   _streamController.addStream(database.groupStream(group));
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    print('dispose');
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

But when I call it the dispose is never called. I call it like this

```
GetBuilder<GroupController>(
        init: GroupController(database, _group),
        builder: (GroupController groupController) => StreamBuilder(
          stream: groupController.stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<GroupModel> groupSnapshot) {
```

I want my controller's dispose method being called whenever the controller is removed from memory.

I noticed that the GetBuilder has a dispose callback. And it requires the state from a widget. So do I need to make the widget that holds the controller statefull? Or do I need to pass a new statefull widget that holds the state? The documentation is not all to clear on it. How do I call the dispose on my controller?

I noticed there is a console log whenever a controller get's deleted from memory, isn't there a callback so I can close the stream there? I would really like to avoid making the widget statefull tho.

**Edit**

```
class GroupController extends GetController{
  StreamController<GroupModel> _streamController = BehaviorSubject();
  Stream<GroupModel> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  GroupController(DatabaseService database, GroupModel group)
  {
   _streamController.addStream(database.groupStream(group));
  }

  @override
  void close(){
    print('log if close is invoked');
    _streamController.close();
    super.close();
  }
}
```

Generate the following log

```
I/flutter (23404): log if close is invoked 
I/flutter (23404): Close can't be called 
I/flutter (23404): [GET] GroupController deleted from memory
```

Somehow it error when trying to close the controller

Comment: When do you expect the `dispose` method to be called?

Comment: When the widget is removed from memory but I want it to happen when the widget is removed from the tree. But in general I would just like to know how to utilize the dispose property of my GetBuilder.

Comment: There is no listener you can put on a class in Dart that will get called when the object is removed from memory. The `dispose` method in widgets _is_ for when they get removed from the widget tree.

Comment: So how do I close the stream with Get? How do I utilize the dispose property of the GetBuilder? And if I pass the dispose method of a statefull widget how can I reference the Controller?

Comment: Simple answer? You can't. The widgets in the get package don't expose a `dispose` property for clean-up code, so you can't really do what you are wanting to do easily. Out of curiosity, though, why are you using get instead of something like provider?

Comment: I switched to Get two days ago I was using provider. I just completely removed Provider because Get seemded to be much more streamlined. I am on a tight deadline and really would just like to figure out how to handle streams with Get Controllers.

Comment: To be honest, the way you are using get seems to be an equivalent but strictly _more_ complicated way of just using a regular old `StreamBuilder`. Regardless, you have your answer and I don't know what else to tell you. Provider's `StreamProvider` has an integrated `dispose` method property which is exactly what you want. Also, get is a much less popular package than provider, so it's going to be harder to find answers to questions you may have. (Doubly so from the fact that you didn't actually say what package you were using so I had to hunt it down myself.)

Comment: In fact Get 'close' all streams that are in the 'close' method automatically when the controller comes out of memory. But the documentation actually lacked that. dispose did nothing, because dispose is a method for disposing of widgets, not controllers, but now the documentation already includes that, as well as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably how you want to be doing it. Not adding the stream in the contructor because this causes problems when the controller get's rebuild. Because it will add the stream to the contructor once more.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class GetStreamController<T> extends GetController {
  final Stream<T> Function() value;
  StreamController<T> _streamController = BehaviorSubject();
  StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;
  Stream<T> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  GetStreamController(this.value);
  @override
  void onInit()
  {
    super.onInit();
    _streamSubscription = value().listen((event) {
      _streamController.add(event);
    });
  }

  @override
  void onClose()
  {
    super.onClose();
    _streamSubscription.cancel();
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is because you have not used a local stream, you have added an existing stream to your local stream, so you need to drain your stream first.
The log presents a generic error because Get has a try catch, and any error thrown within the close method, it throws this same exception, but in fact close was being called, but the stream had an error because it hadn't been drained and this error triggered Get's catch (e).
If there was no _streamController.addStream (database.groupStream (group)); this additional procedure would not be necessary. Your code is 100% secure

Comment: Ok so now I have the following problem. My second GetBuilder calls the close method whenever it get's removed from the widget tree which tries to close the stream. I actually posted on the github page since I'm not really sure how I should use Streams with Controllers https://github.com/jonataslaw/get/issues/94

Comment: I believe the problem was solved in the last update, it was a typo that made any GetBuilder available to call the main GetBuilder device. Thanks for reporting this error, it was clearing the tests, and the test with close streams of child pages was added.

Comment: I updated the code aswell, because I had problems when assigning the stream in the contructor. Because the contructor get's called on every rebuild. The initState does not however!

Answer (score 6):

If you insert a 'dispose' into your GetController, it will be ignored. This is because disposing is a method for discarding widgets in a StatefulWidget class, not for discarding controllers, not least because Get automatically and intelligently discards controllers to free resources when it is no longer needed. If you want to close streams, Get does it automatically, as long as you insert your streams into the onClose method.

```
class GroupController extends GetxController {
  StreamController<GroupModel> _streamController = BehaviorSubject();
  Stream<GroupModel> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  GroupController(DatabaseService database, GroupModel group);
  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    _streamController.addStream(database.groupStream(group));
    super.onInit();
  }

  // this
  @override
  void onClose() {
    print('dispose');
    _streamController.close();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

If you are using an old version of Get, you can use the same close and close method manually:

```
GetBuilder<GroupController>(
        init: GroupController(database, _group),
        builder: (GroupController groupController) => StreamBuilder(
          stream: groupController.stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<GroupModel> groupSnapshot) {
```

Comment: Great, I needed to update my Get apparently. I tried closing the stream in the close method and got the following error `I/flutter (23404): log if close is invoked
I/flutter (23404): Close can't be called
I/flutter (23404): [GET] GroupController deleted from memory` so it does invoke the method but then logs that the close can't be called?

Comment: I added the code I use for the controller at the bottom of my answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aah okay so the stream needs to be drained first. So I had to implement a future which drains the stream and then closes the controller. Not sure how safe this is.

Comment: I added the working code below but accepted your answer since I wanted to find the close callback